# Images not showing in Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, package, embedded-resource

My program runs perfectly in Eclipse, but when I export it, the images dont show up.

My setup looks like

```
src
..gui
....Main.java
....menus
......MenuMain.java
res
...Logo.png
```

I refence Logo.png from MenuMain.java, I tried many way;

- `res/Logo.png`
- `/res/Logo.png`
- `.res/Logo.png`
- `../../Logo.png`
- ++++

The top 3 ones work in Eclipse but neither works in Jar. I checked Jar file, the res folder is there and so are all the images. I also tried to edit MANIFEST.MF and added Class-Path:

But it still doesn't work. I don't get any errors when running the Jar, everything else shows up file (Buttons, labels, ++)

EDIT:
I use this is JPanel with GridBagLayout, I add an ImageIcon to JLabel to be able to add it to the JPanel. Originally I used something like:

```
JLabel logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res/Logo.png"));
```

But I also tried other variations like:

```
JLabel logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(MenuMain.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/res/Logo.png")));
```

And also via `getResourceAsStream()`

Only the first one works in Eclipse, but doesn't show up in Jar. The others just crash (NullPointer)

Comment: is this Swing? Can you post the snippet relevant to reading/rendering the images?

Comment: When you run from a jar, typically the compiled contents of the src folder and all the contents of the res folder need to be together. Then you just load from the classpath.

Comment: @asgs added more info in main post

Comment: @LeeMeador: Yes, I checked the final jar file, its still consistent with the path I give; there is a res folder in root which contains said image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Logo.png in your jar, and load the resource from the classpath using [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

The general pattern is:

```
...
InputStream resource = className.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/Logo.png");
Image image = ImageIO.read(resource);
// do your display stuff here...
...
```

Comment: I have Logo.png in my jar.

And I also have tried atleast 10 variations of your code, but then I cant run it in eclipse (Didnt try to export it, so i dont know if that works).

Comment: Ok, then use `getResourceAsStream()` instead of `FileInputStream`

Comment: InputStream resource = MenuMain.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/Logo.png");
  JLabel logo = new JLabel();
  try {
   logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(resource)));
  } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

Gives Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Comment: (I tried all kinds of variations of path, like the ones i listed if original post, but when I use getResourceAsStream it never finds it)

Comment: @PaulProgrammer - your code sample doesn't match the method you are asking the OP to use, which is probably why its not working for him. The code should be more like this - `MenuMain.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/res/Logo.png");`.

Comment: The way I always do it is to put the resource in the same folder as the .class file loading it. That way I don't have to remember or figure out the funky rules for loading from the classpath. You can use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Logo.png");` and it works.

Comment: That probably is true, but I have a lot of graphics and resources so it will quickly become messy if I put it all together.